# How can I get Hadoop with Cascading to show me debug log output?

Tags: debugging, logging, hadoop, stdout, cascading

I'm having trouble getting Hadoop and [Cascading](http://www.cascading.org/) 1.2.6 to show me the output that's supposed to come from using the [Debug](http://www.cascading.org/1.2/javadoc/cascading/operation/Debug.html) filter.  The [Cascading guide says this is how you can view the current tuples](http://www.cascading.org/1.2/userguide/htmlsingle/#N20F24). I'm using this to try to see any debug output:

```
Debug debug = new Debug(Debug.Output.STDOUT, true);
debug.setPrintTupleEvery(1);
debug.setPrintFieldsEvery(1);
assembly = new Each( assembly, DebugLevel.VERBOSE, debug );
```

I'm pretty new to Hadoop and Cascading, but it's possible I'm not looking in the right place or that there's some simple log4j setting that I'm missing (I haven't made any changes to the defaults you get with Cloudera `hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u3`.

This is the WordCount sample class that I'm using (copied from the [cascading user guide](http://www.cascading.org/1.2/userguide/htmlsingle/#N2009C)) with Debug statements added in:

```
package org.cascading.example;

import cascading.flow.Flow;
import cascading.flow.FlowConnector;
import cascading.operation.Aggregator;
import cascading.operation.Debug;
import cascading.operation.DebugLevel;
import cascading.operation.Function;
import cascading.operation.aggregator.Count;
import cascading.operation.regex.RegexGenerator;
import cascading.pipe.Each;
import cascading.pipe.Every;
import cascading.pipe.GroupBy;
import cascading.pipe.Pipe;
import cascading.scheme.Scheme;
import cascading.scheme.TextLine;
import cascading.tap.Hfs;
import cascading.tap.SinkMode;
import cascading.tap.Tap;
import cascading.tuple.Fields;

import java.util.Properties;

public class WordCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputPath = args[0];
        String outputPath = args[1];

        // define source and sink Taps.
        Scheme sourceScheme = new TextLine( new Fields( "line" ) );
        Tap source = new Hfs( sourceScheme, inputPath );

        Scheme sinkScheme = new TextLine( new Fields( "word", "count" ) );
        Tap sink = new Hfs( sinkScheme, outputPath, SinkMode.REPLACE );

        // the 'head' of the pipe assembly
        Pipe assembly = new Pipe( "wordcount" );

        // For each input Tuple
        // using a regular expression
        // parse out each word into a new Tuple with the field name "word"
        String regex = "(?<!\\pL)(?=\\pL)[^ ]*(?<=\\pL)(?!\\pL)";
        Function function = new RegexGenerator( new Fields( "word" ), regex );

        assembly = new Each( assembly, new Fields( "line" ), function );

        Debug debug = new Debug(Debug.Output.STDOUT, true);
        debug.setPrintTupleEvery(1);
        debug.setPrintFieldsEvery(1);
        assembly = new Each( assembly, DebugLevel.VERBOSE, debug );

        // group the Tuple stream by the "word" value
        assembly = new GroupBy( assembly, new Fields( "word" ) );

        // For every Tuple group
        // count the number of occurrences of "word" and store result in
        // a field named "count"
        Aggregator count = new Count( new Fields( "count" ) );
        assembly = new Every( assembly, count );

        // initialize app properties, tell Hadoop which jar file to use
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        FlowConnector.setApplicationJarClass( properties, WordCount.class );

        // plan a new Flow from the assembly using the source and sink Taps
        FlowConnector flowConnector = new FlowConnector();
        FlowConnector.setDebugLevel( properties, DebugLevel.VERBOSE );
        Flow flow = flowConnector.connect( "word-count", source, sink, assembly );

        // execute the flow, block until complete
        flow.complete();

        // Ask Cascading to create a GraphViz DOT file
        // brew install graphviz # install viewer to look at dot file
        flow.writeDOT("build/flow.dot");
    }
}
```

It works fine, I just can't find any debug statements anywhere showing me the words.  I've looked both through the HDFS filesystem with `hadoop dfs -ls` as well as through the [jobtracker web ui](http://localhost:50030/jobtracker.jsp). The log output for a mapper in the jobtracker doesn't have any output for STDOUT:

```
Task Logs: 'attempt_201203131143_0022_m_000000_0'



stdout logs


stderr logs
2012-03-13 14:32:24.642 java[74752:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore


syslog logs
2012-03-13 14:32:24,786 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: JAAS Configuration already set up for Hadoop, not re-installing.
2012-03-13 14:32:25,278 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2012-03-13 14:32:25,617 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=MAP, sessionId=
2012-03-13 14:32:25,903 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : null
2012-03-13 14:32:25,945 INFO cascading.tap.hadoop.MultiInputSplit: current split input path: hdfs://localhost/usr/tnaleid/shakespeare/input/comedies/cymbeline
2012-03-13 14:32:25,980 WARN org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
2012-03-13 14:32:25,988 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
2012-03-13 14:32:26,002 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
2012-03-13 14:32:26,246 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
2012-03-13 14:32:26,247 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
2012-03-13 14:32:27,623 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
2012-03-13 14:32:28,274 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
2012-03-13 14:32:28,310 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task:attempt_201203131143_0022_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
2012-03-13 14:32:28,337 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_201203131143_0022_m_000000_0' done.
2012-03-13 14:32:28,361 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogsTruncater: Initializing logs' truncater with mapRetainSize=-1 and reduceRetainSize=-1
```

At the end, I'm also writing out the DOT file, which does not have the Debug statement in it that I'd expect (though maybe those are stripped out):

[image: word count flow diagram]

Is there some log file somewhere that I'm missing, or is it a config setting that I need to set?

Comment: Also, I just tried a "normal" map reduce job and printing to `System.out.println` in the job _does_ output to the log file in the jobtracker UI: `Task Logs: 'attempt_201203131143_0023_m_000000_0'



stdout logs
line-> CYMBELINE
...`

Answer (score 2):

I got an answer from the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/cascading-user/browse_thread/thread/e77f3ccbf56c613) on this.

Changing it to this works:

```
assembly = new Each( assembly, new Fields( "line" ), function );

// simpler debug statement
assembly = new Each( assembly, new Debug("hello", true) );

assembly = new GroupBy( assembly, new Fields( "word" ) );
```

That outputs this in the jobdetails UI under stderr:

```
Task Logs: 'attempt_201203131143_0028_m_000000_0'



stdout logs


stderr logs
2012-03-13 16:21:41.304 java[78617:1903] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
hello: ['word']
hello: ['CYMBELINE']
<SNIP>
```

I had tried this directly from the docs, and that doesn't work for me (even though I've also set the FlowConnector debugLevel to VERBOSE):

```
assembly = new Each( assembly, DebugLevel.VERBOSE, new Debug() );
```

It seems that it's something related to the DebugLevel.VERBOSE from the documentation as when I try this, I still get no output:

```
assembly = new Each( assembly, DebugLevel.VERBOSE, new Debug("hello", true) );
```

Changing it to remove the DebugLevel also gives me output

```
assembly = new Each( assembly, new Debug() );
```

I can also get it to switch to stdout by doing this:

```
assembly = new Each( assembly, new Debug(Debug.Output.STDOUT) );
```

I'm betting there's still something I've got misconfigured with the `VERBOSE` log level stuff, or 1.2.6 doesn't match the documentation anymore, but at least now I can see the output in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting

> flow.setDebugLevel( DebugLevel.VERBOSE );